# VBA - Find Last Column

Tags: vba

Below is a copy of my data. I've been trying to find the last column + 1 (so in this example, it should be 4, since last column is C and plus 1). The code I'm using is to determine last column is:

`lastColumn = Cells(lastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

But I keep getting 2?

[image]

Comment: I assume `lastRow` is 10 (your last row of data), and in that row, only 2 columns are filled. Use the row where you have your header (5). Or dig into https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/7599798

Comment: @FunThomas my god, i can't believe i didn't see this. Yep it worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`lastColumn = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

result will be 3 (last column on row 5)

`lastColumn = Cells(lastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

result will be 2 (last column on row 10)

Answer (score 0):

```
lastColumn = Cells(**5**, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Was using lastrow and in that row, only two columns were filled. Used the header row instead.